# python3.6 win7x86 how to use Buzzer on the board?

Tags: python, windows-7, beep

I have use the follow code success in Windows XP, but it seems to have failed in Windows 7.

```html
print('\a')
```

or use `beep.sys`

```html
beep(100,100)
```

How do I make the Buzzer on the board loud in Windows 7? I try the `winIO.dll`, but always initial failed, always return `0(False)`.

Comment: Please post the error as well

Comment: Will be work `print('\a')` but required run code on `system`(`CMD`) not `IDLE`, on CMD  `C:\PythonXX\python.exe path_of_your_script\your_awesome.py`

Comment: it works well in xp, but in the Win7, the default  loudspeaker speak not the Buzzer. the same code, i search the google, as win7 changes the beep.sys